# Simultaneously read and write binary file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, io, binary

I want to write and read a binary file simultaneously, but whenever I try to do so I always get an exception stating that the file is already in use by a different process. I know  how to do it with a normal `FileStream` but with a `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` it doesn't work.

Does anybody have an idea how to read and write a binary file simultaneously?

What I've done so far:

```vb
FileSt = New FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite)
writer = New BinaryWriter(FileSt, enc)
reader = New BinaryReader(File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Open))
```

Comment: Further to the answers provided, if you intend to open the same file twice - once for reading and once for writing - then you should be using `FileAccess.Read` for one and `FileAccess.Write` for the other. Also, don't open the file once with a `FileStream` constructor and once with `File.Open`. Be consistent and use the same method both times. Also, open the file with a `Using` block so that it can be closed implicitly when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening the file twice - once for reading and once for writing. That means that one `FileStream` needs `FileAccess.Read` and `FileShare.Write` while the other needs `FileAccess.Write` and `FileShare.Read`.  This code is tested and verified with a file that had already had an `Integer` and a `String` written to it with a `BinaryWriter`:

```
Dim filePath As String = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Test.bin")

Using source = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Write),
      destination = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read),
      reader As New BinaryReader(source),
      writer As New BinaryWriter(destination)
    Dim n = reader.ReadInt32()

    writer.Write(98765)
    writer.Write("What's up doc?")

    Dim sz = reader.ReadString()
End Using
```

Note that you should only specify `Read` or `Write` if that's all that's needed.  Only specify `ReadWrite` if you know that you will or might need both.  The `FileAccess` value is for what this `FileStream` will do or may do to the file while the `FileShare` value is for what other `FileStream` objects opened on the same file are allowed to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `FileStream` [constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh(v=vs.110).aspx) that can provide [`FileShare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) mode.

See what MSDN states about `FileShare.ReadWrite` mode:

> Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading or writing. If this
>   flag is not specified, any request to open the file for reading or
>   writing (by this process or another process) will fail until the file
>   is closed. However, even if this flag is specified, additional
>   permissions might still be needed to access the file.

Comment: Fidemraizer: Even with FileShare.ReadWrite i get the same error

Comment: @Eggord I doubt it. In fact you're opening the whole file twice with different flags. Try to open both with `FileShare.ReadWrite` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the FileShare mode on the file.

```
        FileStream blah = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: As noted by others, you need to change the second open as well:
  FileStream binaryReaderFile = File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);